# Static view across pages

Tags: xamarin.forms

There's been a few forum posts/SO posts about this, but they're a few years old and didn't provide any solutions, so here we go again.

I want to have a view, which is static across pages. I have a `TabbedPage`, and I want to show a bar just above the bottom tabs.
Currently I am using a `ControlTemplate` on my pages, which puts the bar at the bottom and shows content above it. But there's a few things I don't like about this solution:

- A new instance of the view is created for each tab. So for X amount of tabs, the view is instantiated and shown X times. This also means that whenever I change some of the data that's being shown from the view model, there are X times as many bindings to be updated.
- When changing tabs, the whole page swipes out of the screen, while the new one swipes in. That includes this bottom bar. I really just want it to stay in place across different navigation.

Another not-so-optimal solution I've seen someone suggest, is implementing my own tab view instead of a page, and each tab is a view instead of a page. There are a few reasons why this isn't feasible for me:

- Each tab is a navigation page which can have navigation. If going this way, I'd have to also remake navigation page as a view, and change the content.
- Xamarin Forms navigation can no longer be used.
- I'm using a library for transition animations when navigating between pages (not between tabs). It only works with actual navigation, which this solution completely removes from the app.

Can it really be true, that this case is not possible with Xamarin Forms? It's not that rare a use case. Basically any app that plays audio, will want to have a play-bar at the bottom to control current playback etc.

I guess this could be solved with a kind of view which can render a page. Then I could make my "master view" that show the `TabbedPage` below my static view.

Another (possibly more suited) way to go, could maybe be a custom `TabbedPage`, with an "OverlayView" property, which is somehow with custom renderer added above the tabs?

EDIT: Here's a photo of the view I want to be static across tabs. I hope it helps you to understand the outcome I'm trying to achieve.
[image: Now playing]

Comment: "It's not that rare a use case" - I'd say that it is.  You're using a Tabbed UI, and it's pretty standard that each tab's content is independent.

Comment: Yeah, each tab's content is independent. The point is I don't want the static view to be part of the tab content.
YouTube Music has it, Spotify has it Pockets Casts has it. Basically any audio player has it.

Comment: @Jason I've added a screenshot to my post, to make it more clear what I'm trying to ahieve. I think maybe you misunderstood, since this really isn't a rare use case.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to incorporate that into a custom tab navigation control.  No idea how easy it would be to do it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a kind of workaround. Using https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup - I can make my "now playing"-bar as a "popup". By setting `BackgroundInputTransparent` to true, I can show it on top of all other views. It's quite simple, actually.